# jQuery stop nth-child selecting child nested elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Building an A/B test in jQuery, structure of the HTML within the original page is:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
```

But when I use div ul li:nth-child(1).addClass("test"); it adds that class to all 'li' elements..

How do I stop it adding the class to all li elements and just keep it to the first li?

Answer (score 2):

Use [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors):

```
div ul > li:nth-child(1).addClass("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [jQuery's `children()` method](http://api.jquery.com/children/) on your `div` element to select the `ul` element which is a direct child of that `div`. You can then use `find()` to pull the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) `li` element.

```
$('div').children('ul').find('li:first').addClass('test')
```

Or you can use [jQuery's `first()` method](http://api.jquery.com/first/) instead of its `:first` selector:

```
$('div').children('ul').find('li').first().addClass('test')
```

#### Demo

```js
$('div').children('ul').find('li:first').addClass('test')
```

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
          Not-nested List Item (should have border)
            <ul>
                <li>
                  Nested List Item (should not have border)
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah thanks guys, makes perfect sense and works like a dream. Thanks again

Comment: Note this pattern will not work correctly for multiple lists. `nth-child` would be the better option then.